# How can I get the x and y coordinate values for the region with the highest count / "hottest" in a Hexbin plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a line symmetry detector for a project I've found on [github](https://github.com/dramenti/symmetry) and it makes use of matplotlib's hexbin plot to identify coordinates to find the symmetric line.

Unfortunately, this method is very manual and requires the user to identify the x and y coordinates through the generated plot, and then input the values into the program again.

Is there a way to return the x and y values where the region is hottest in the hexbin plot?

For reference, [this is the generated hexbin plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUBdg.png). The coordinates I am looking for is roughly x=153.0 y=1.535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.hexbin` returns a `PolyCollection` object, which has the X and Y positions and their values, [see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html). You can access them with `get_offsets()` and `get_array()`. Here's an example:

```py
# Figure from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-hexbin-function-in-python/
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
    
np.random.seed(19680801) 
    
n = 100000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n) 
y = 12 * np.random.standard_normal(n) 
     
polycollection = plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize = 50, cmap ='Greens') 
# New part
max_ = polycollection.get_array().max()
max_pos = polycollection.get_array().argmax()
pos_x, pos_y = polycollection.get_offsets()[max_pos]
plt.text(pos_x, pos_y, max_, color='w')
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image]